# Alguna manera de subir una aplicacion hecha en ANGULAR a github Pages para que se vea bien?

Tags: javascript, angular

Hola chicos estoy intentando subir una aplicación que hice en Angular a GitHub Pages pero esta no se ve bien aparece en blanco, pero cuando la subo a Netlify si funciona alguien sabe por que pasa?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: hola que es 2cooldevs.github.io?

Comment: Saludos bro, estoy utilizando github pages, ese es mi username, en GitHub.

Comment: Tenes configurado `git config --global user.name "Tu nombre aquí"
git config --global user.email "tu_email_aquí@example.com"` seguiste luego los tutoriales `https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/crear-repositorio-git-codigo.html `

Comment: claro, esa configuracion es la primera que se hace para utilizar git,

Comment: la foto no es suficiente como para poder ayudarte no sabemos que pasos seguiste para crear y subir el proyecto no hay cosas obvias en un codigo que no vemos

Comment: Al parecer no se puede hacer el despliegue en github pages

Comment: no lo había hecho antes probé con un borrador de codigo que tengo en github y lo muestra en github page te lo agrego como respuesta

Comment: como te describo en mi respuesta si es posible hacer el despliegue en GitHub. Tenes alguna dificultad adicional por la cual mi respuesta no te es de utilidad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como  describo en mi respuesta si es posible hacer el despliegue en GitHub. Tenes alguna dificultad adicional por la cual mi respuesta no te es de utilidad?

> Podemos desplegar una aplicación Angular en github  Pages de diversas
> formas   Una de ellas mediante la creación de un repositorio con
> nuestro nombre de usuario seguido de .github.io en GitHub :

1. crear un repo que sera
   un repositorio de  Páginas de GitHub en mi caso ya estaba creado por eso el aviso
   [image: inicio repo de paginas]

.[image: repo para page]

2.En el angular.json de tu proyecto modificar  "outputPath": "docs/" para que al hacer el depliegue se use luego como default

```js
....................
"architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "docs/",
            ......................................
```

Desplegamos entonces en la carpeta que se creara

```js
ng build --prod --baseHref="https://nestdanchia.github.io/Form/"
```

Asi se vera la carpeta
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
3. en github en el settings de nuestro proyecto a desplegar bajamos hasta GitHub Pages seleccionamos main,docs y cualquier theme si no se selecciona da error 404 por lo menos en mi caso
[image: github page]

Asi te dara la direccion en la cual fue publicado en mi caso el borrador de codigo desplegado en link al repositorio-->[repo Form](https://github.com/nestdanchia/Form)
Asi quedara desplegado:
[[desplegado en github pages](https://nestdanchia.github.io/Form/)][6](https://nestdanchia.github.io/Form/)

Otros metodos usando librerias.....gh-pages....[despliegue con librerias](https://medium.com/tech-insights/how-to-deploy-angular-apps-to-github-pages-gh-pages-896c4e10f9b4)

Utilizando  Netlify también podemos desplegar nuestra aplicación netlify usa la carpeta dist podemos poner un prefijo o nombre a nuestro dominio y Netlify publica al proyecto en una URL publica
[Netlif Github](https://medium.com/front-end-chile/como-hacer-deploy-manual-de-tu-aplicaci%C3%B3n-angular-a-netlify-52c00e900828)

> Tambien podemos ingresar directamente en la pagina  de [pagina de
> netlify](https://www.netlify.com/) y agregar algún proyecto de Github la pagina es muy
> intuitiva recordar quitar de .gitignore --> /dist .Asi directamente y sin
> necesidad de configurar  a un domineo personalizado podremos ver
> desplegada a nuestra aplicación en forma muy simple e intuitiva
> [directamente desde pagina de netlify](https://fervent-darwin-822980.netlify.app/)
> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
> [image: deploy]